# Sending single attachment to default e-mail client using mailto: in OSX desktop app

Tags: macos, default, attachment, mailto, email-client

I am developing a desktop application which deals with images. I want to provide a feature that e-mails selected image (single image) to the default e-mail client. So, I am using `mailto:` as follows:

```
NSString *eMail = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"mailto:?subject=Test&body=Image];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: eMail]];
```

How do I send the image as an attachment using `mailto:`?

I tried the following: But, it does not work.

```
NSString *eMail = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"mailto:?subject=Test&body=Image&attachment=%@", @"Test.png"];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: eMail]];
```

What can I try next?